# Grid Index Features ArcMap 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, vector-grid

I am developing a custom script to create something like the Split tool but in Basic License level.

So, at first, I Would like to create an Index Grid Feature Tool over my rectangle (this rectangle entire hover my raster) ,but.... The problem is that this Tool automatically DONT calculate the Polygon Width and Polygon Height.... But in arcMap 10.2 it DOES!? Why?

Have i problem with some configuration of my ArcGIS?

Is something changed in this tool from version 10.0 ?

Or can someone help me how can i get the right polygon width and height other way?

Comment: So, your code worked in Arcmap 10.0, but no longer works in 10.2 due to changes in a built in tool?

Comment: No, tool works in 10.2 little bit differently as in 10.0...it is clear but i didnt find any information about it...

Answer (score 2):

If you are having problems creating an index to use with a **"Split for Basic"** tool by using the **[Grid Index Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00700000000q000000)** tool, then I recommend that you switch to using the **[Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000)** tool.

You can run this interactively and then use **Copy As Python Snippet** from the **Geoprocessing | Results** window to copy the syntax into your script.

As an aside I have already written a Split for Basic tool, and I am happy to share that code if I see that asked in a separate Question here.